# Object oriented style app with express.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, oop, express, socket.io

I'm building an application in node, using express for simplify things and socket.io for sockets manipulation.

So, while I'm writing my code I realize that it works, but is not the best and elegant solution.

The only thing I want to do is to wrap all the code of the sockets events, and then reuse in more than one page request, so:

*app.js*

```
var express = require('express')
  , io;

var app = express()
  , PORT = 7777;

io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(PORT)); 

app.get("/", function ( req, res ) {
  io.socket.on('connection', function ( socket ) { 
    socket.on('user', function () {

    });
    socket.on('message', function () {

    });
    socket.on('getConversation', function ( socket ) {

    });
  });

  res.render('index');
});
```

But what happens if I want to assign to the `/foo` and `/bar` files the same approach?

i.e. I need to get it in a modular or object oriented way, as can be possible.

There is a pattern to do it?

Comment: sockets are usually seperated from the routes, it makes no sense to have event listeners listening for connections on websocket inside a route listening for a HTTP connection.

Comment: So, can you give an example?

Comment: Nope, not really, as it's not needed, websockets have their own connection, so you shouldn't place the event handlers for those connections inside an event handler that is waiting for a HTTP connection. Just place the socket stuff outside app.get

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're doing here is attaching event listeners to socket.io after someone makes a page request. Then every single request after that would be attaching *new* event listeners and your server slowly begins to run out of memory as you clog it with new event listeners every time someone makes a page request. It makes no sense to put socket.io code in your route handlers. Take a look at this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express.io